# AWS CodeBuild terraform init "no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found."

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild

Terraform 1.2.7

I have AWS CodeBuild which is assuming role `devops`

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "code_build" {
  name          = "${var.app_name}-${var.target_env}-${var.build_project}"
  description   = "${var.app_name} ${var.build_project} pipeline on ${var.target_env}"
  service_role  = arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/devops
....
```

`devops` role has a policy that allows to be assumed by codebuild service and comes with admin privileges

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Admin privileges

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Terraform backend config

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }
  
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "tfstatebucket"
    key            = "infrastructure/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "eu-central-1"
    role_arn       = "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/devops"
    dynamodb_table = "cdc-terraform-up-and-running-lock"
    encrypt        = true
  }
}
```

`Buildspec.yaml`

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - |
        if [ -n "$INSTALL_TOOLS_SCRIPT" ]; then
          ./$INSTALL_TOOLS_SCRIPT
        fi
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - |
        if [ -n "$PREBUILD_SCRIPT" ]; then
          ./$PREBUILD_SCRIPT
        fi
  build:
    commands:
      - |
        if [ -n "$BUILD_SCRIPT" ]; then
          ./$BUILD_SCRIPT
        fi
  post_build:
    commands:
      - |
        if [ -n "$POSTBUILD_SCRIPT" ]; then
          ./$POSTBUILD_SCRIPT
        fi
```

`install_tools.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euxo pipefail

function install_terraform() {
    echo Installing Terraform...
    
    curl -s -qL -o terraform_install.zip https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.2.7/terraform_1.2.7_linux_amd64.zip
    unzip terraform_install.zip -d /usr/bin/
    chmod +x /usr/bin/terraform

    terraform --version 
}

install_terraform
```

`prebuild.sh`

```
set -euxo pipefail

echo Terraform init...
terraform init
```

I am able to succesfully assume the role and `terraform init/plan/apply` on local machine, but it fails on CodeBuild

[image]

`Update`

I've removed `roleArn` from backend config and provider and the issue still persists

`Updated Terraform backend config`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }
  
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "tfstatebucket"
    key            = "infrastructure/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "eu-central-1"       
    dynamodb_table = "cdc-terraform-up-and-running-lock"
    encrypt        = true
  }
}
```

`Updated provider`

```
provider "aws" {
  region = lookup(var.aws_region, var.env)

  allowed_account_ids = [
    lookup(var.account_id, var.env),
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE**
For the sake of it I have manually attempted assume-role via cli succesfully. However, terraform init still fails, complaining about wrong session token. How is that even possible?

**Log Output**

```
+ aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::***:role/devops --role-session-name codebuild
+ cat creds
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "***",
        "SecretAccessKey": "***",
        "SessionToken": "***",
        "Expiration": "2022-08-23T21:47:47+00:00"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "***:codebuild",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::***:assumed-role/devops/codebuild"
    }
}
++ jq .Credentials.AccessKeyId
+ export 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="*"'
+ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='"*"'

++ jq .Credentials.SecretAccessKey
+ export 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="*"'
+ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='"*"'

++ jq .Credentials.SessionToken
+ export 'AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="*"'
+ AWS_SESSION_TOKEN='"*"'


+ terraform init
Initializing modules...
- aws_appautoscaling_ecs_consumer_target in tfmodules/autoscaling
- aws_appautoscaling_ecs_server_target in tfmodules/autoscaling
- aws_appautoscaling_ecs_websocket_server_target in tfmodules/autoscaling

Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: error configuring S3 Backend: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
│   status code: 403, request id: 87aedbae-938c-4019-a82a-47a53dfe06f5
│
```

**Associated code with the above output**

```bash
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::***:role/devops --role-session-name codebuild > creds

cat creds

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(cat creds | jq '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(cat creds | jq '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(cat creds | jq '.Credentials.SessionToken')
```

Comment: What version of terraform? How are you invoking terraform, what does the project config look like?

Comment: see updated description

Comment: I would try removing the `role_arn` setting from the backend configuration. That is telling terraform to assume a specific role, instead of using the temporary credentials exposed by the CodeBuild environment (which has already assumed that role). I just looked through a project where I have this working, and that's the only difference I see between your configuration and mine.

Comment: @MarkB you are already guiding me in the right direction. I've checked the terraform official docs and it says "If provided with a role ARN, the AWS Provider will attempt to assume this role using the supplied credentials." So, indeed is expecting credentials. What I am afraid, if I remove `roleArn`, is that local users will be able to manipulate AWS resources through terraform without being able to assume that role (i.e don't have the permissions)

Comment: I've removed `roleArn` from the backend config and provider and the issue still persists

Comment: Any change it's related to this: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/23131 ?

Comment: @JFCorleone I’ve come across that  post as well, I’ve downgraded to aws provider version 3 and that one should work, but it doesn’t…

Comment: @MarkB even exporting AWS credentials is not solving the issue. Any idea how could that be possible. Succesfully assuming the role, getting the credentials, parsing them and exposing the necessary environment variables, yet terraform (aws provider) complains about invalid client token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find the issue.
Internally aws sdk is querying the credentials endpoint `169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` for credentials. Because my CodeBuild instance was configured to run in private VPC, it had to go through corporate proxy for external resources. In `no_proxy/NO_PROXY` config only the instance metadata IP (`169.254.169.254`) was whitelisted. Whitelisting `169.254.170.2` in my proxy configuration solved the problem.